# convert a string to byte array

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to convert my hex string to byte and save it to a byte array.I saw the code on the internet and tried to adapt it to my program.But i am at a complete loss.I am quite new to java.Could some one please help me in doing my conversion.Below is the code i wrote.
Thank you

```
public class Main {

    static String s = "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";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) +
                               Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;

    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this program?  What's the problem?

Comment: I want to get the corresponding byte value in my console .How do i do to display that

Comment: Well, how exactly do you expect the bytes to be printed?  Just as a list: `{0, 100, -20, ...}`?

Comment: convert it back to an hexadecimal string, and display this string ;-)

Comment: Right now you're never calling the method in your `main`

Comment: Is your problem just that you don't know how to call the method?

Comment: Have you seen [this?](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/hexStringToByteArray.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The code works if you call the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="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";
    byte[] b = hexStringToByteArray(s);
    System.out.println(b);

    //edit:
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
}
```

Comment: [B@1e63e3d--- that is what appears in my console already got that before it is the location of the last byte value and not the all the byte values itself.I need a corresponding byte values at every location in the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple utility class check [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/ning/metrics.serialization-all/1.1.0/metrics.serialization-all-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies-sources.jar!/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.java?format=ok). Below is the example where we are converting from `hex string` to `byte[]` and then to `hex string` and then we are comparing to see if conversion was good.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "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";
    String str1 = new String(encodeHex(hexStringToByteArray(str)));
    if (str1.equals(str)) {
        System.out.println("String matches ");
    }
}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String str) {

    char[] data = str.toCharArray();
    int len = data.length;
    byte[] out = new byte[len >> 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++) {
        int f = Character.digit(data[j], 16) << 4;
        j++;
        f = f | Character.digit(data[j], 16);
        j++;
        out[i] = (byte) (f & 0xFF);
    }
    return out;
}

public static char[] encodeHex(byte[] data) {

    int l = data.length;
    char[] out = new char[l << 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++) {
        out[j++] = DIGITS[(0xF0 & data[i]) >>> 4];
        out[j++] = DIGITS[0x0F & data[i]];
    }

    return out;
}

private static final char[] DIGITS = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
        '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
}
```

Output:

```
 String matches
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run java program its call to main method and in your case which is empty. you have to call your methods in main method. Since you have static hexStringToByteArray method you can call it like this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    hexStringToByteArray(s);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I should be reading better. I thought your question was about the conversion, but I now think it's about the display. If it's about the display, others here have noted that you're not calling anything in your main method (which is where the magic happens). If it's about the conversion, BigInterger can do the heavy lifting for you. Just in case: this will work (last 5 lines are just to check if the output matches the input).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(s, 16).toByteArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));

    List<String> hexToCheck = new ArrayList<String>(bytes.length);
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        hexToCheck.add(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    System.out.println(hexToCheck);
}
```

(if the correct answer to your question is filling the main method, please choose one of the other responses as the right answer)