# Convert binary string to byte array

Tags: java, string, syntax, binary, byte

I have a string of ones and zeros that I want to convert to an array of bytes.

For example `String b = "0110100001101001"` How can I convert this to a `byte[]` of length 2?

Comment: @kocko he has 16 bits...

Comment: Based off of string b, you want a byte[] length 2 with `104` in position 0, and `105` in position 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert a string to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185073/convert-a-string-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Parse it to an integer in base 2, then convert to a byte array.  In fact, since you've got 16 bits it's time to break out the rarely used `short`.

```
short a = Short.parseShort(b, 2);
ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(a);

byte[] array = bytes.array();
```

Comment: What if the String contains too many bits that it can't be hold even in a `long` variable?

Comment: If the string is too big, then you'll get a `NumberFormatException`.  I'm making assumptions that it's less than 32 characters for this small example.

Comment: Then this is not a bullet-proof solution. Is there any with simple code or it involves manual working on the String contents?

Comment: I'm not sure this could get much simple?  If `b` is in an invalid format a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown and it's up to the callee to handle the error.  Open to suggestions on how to improve this, but I think this is enough of an answer to illustrate the point.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza using `BigInteger` as the other answer suggested will take care of that issue.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. I should have been more clear though, I split the string every 8 characters so I only needed to loop through the split string and add it to the byte[] array.

Answer (score 25):

Another simple approach is:

```
String b = "0110100001101001";
byte[] bval = new BigInteger(b, 2).toByteArray();
```

Comment: it cannot parse "1110100001101001"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158629/biginteger-tobytearray-returns-purposeful-leading-zeros

You might have some sign issues.

Comment: When I'm displaying byte[] fspec = new BigInteger("10000000", 2).toByteArray();, it shows [B@3b22cdd0 instead of expected value - why?

Comment: @Line Because you're displaying it wrong. See [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784/5221149)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your binary String can be divided by 8 without getting a rest you can use following method:

```
/**
 * Get an byte array by binary string
 * @param binaryString the string representing a byte
 * @return an byte array
 */
public static byte[] getByteByString(String binaryString){
    Iterable iterable = Splitter.fixedLength(8).split(binaryString);
    byte[] ret = new byte[Iterables.size(iterable) ];
    Iterator iterator = iterable.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer byteAsInt = Integer.parseInt(iterator.next().toString(), 2);
        ret[i] = byteAsInt.byteValue();
        i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Don't forget to add the [guava lib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava) to your dependecies.

In Android you should add to app gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
```

And add this into project gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

[This post contains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40847030/1386969) a solution without using Guava Lib.