# How to convert binary string to the byte array of 2 bytes in java

Tags: java, binary, byte, arrays, binary-data

I have binary string `String A = "1000000110101110"`. I want to convert this string into byte array of length 2 in `java`

I have taken the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727310/convert-binary-string-to-byte-array) link

I have tried to convert it into byte by various ways

1. I have converted that string into decimal first and then apply the code to store into the byte array

   ```
   int aInt = Integer.parseInt(A, 2);
           byte[] xByte = new byte[2];
       xByte[0] = (byte) ((aInt >> 8) & 0XFF);
       xByte[1] = (byte) (aInt & 0XFF);
       System.arraycopy(xByte, 0, record, 0,
               xByte.length);
   ```

But the values get store into the byte array are negative

```
xByte[0] :-127
xByte[1] :-82
```

Which are wrong values.

2.I have also tried using

```
byte[] xByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).putInt(aInt).array();
```

But it throws the exception at the above line like

```
  java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:519)     at
  java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:366)   at
  org.com.app.convert.generateTemplate(convert.java:266)
```

What should i do now to convert the binary string to byte array of 2 bytes?Is there any inbuilt function  in `java` to get the byte array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are getting

```
 xByte[0] :-127
 xByte[1] :-82
```

is right.

This is called 2's compliment Represantation.
1st bit is used as signed bit.

```
0 for +ve
1 for -ve
```

if 1st bit is 0 than it calculates as regular.
but if 1st bit is 1 than it deduct the values of 7 bit from 128 and what ever the answer is presented in -ve form.

In your case
1st value is`10000001`
so 1(1st bit) for -ve and 128 - 1(last seven bits) = 127
so value is -127

For more detail read 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String s = "1000000110101110";
int i = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
byte[] a = {(byte) ( i >> 8), (byte) i};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & a[0]) + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & a[1]));
```

output

```
[-127, -82]
10000001 10101110
```

that is -127 == 0xb10000001 and -82 == 0xb10101110

Comment: That’s more compact but does not differ from what the questioner already did in the first attempt.

Comment: I have tried with your method `byte[] xByte = {(byte) ( aInt >> 8), (byte) aInt};` But the value stored in the zeroth place is still negative `xByte[0] :-127`

Comment: @rachana: And that won’t change. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `putShort` for putting a two byte value. `int` has four bytes.

```
// big endian is the default order
byte[] xByte = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort((short)aInt).array();
```

By the way, *your first attempt is perfect*. You can’t change the negative sign of the bytes as the most significant bit of these bytes is set. That’s always interpreted as negative value.

10000001₂ == -127

10101110₂ == -82

Comment: Can you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 2):

Bytes are signed 8 bit integers. As such your result is completely correct. 
That is: 01111111 is 127, but 10000000 is -128. If you want to get numbers in 0-255 range you need to use a bigger variable type like short.

You can print byte as unsigned like this:

```
public static String toString(byte b) {
    return String.valueOf(((short)b) & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain that with an example?

Comment: Explain what? How to use shorts? Just replace byte[] with short[] and replace `(byte)` casts with `(short)` casts and you'll get 0-255 values. Java byte represents numbers in [-128, 127] range.

Comment: But I want the byte array if I use short[] replacing byte[] it will give short[] and this is not what I want

Comment: well with byte array each element represents 256 possible values, which are in -128 to 127 range as far as arithmetic operations are concerned. Also java built-in functions to print them to String are going to use these values. You can print bytes to 0-255 strings yourself if you want to. I will edit my answer with a function that prints a byte in that range.