# Export string with bytes to file without encoding

Tags: java, string, byte

I stored bytes within a string in Java

```
String header ="00110011000000011001000000000001001011000000000100000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
```

Now i want to write that String to a file, but export that as a series of bits and not encoded as a text. 
Writing to the file looks like this:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("test.epd"));
writer.write(header);
```

How can I do this(The string in this prog will be longer --> around 8kB)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary to text in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert binary string to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727310/convert-binary-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: @fvu But his string is just 16bit long so he can use a variable to store the string .. In my case no variable will be long enough! As i said i need about 8kB

Comment: read in chunks of 8/16/32 characters

Answer (score 1):

I would use [BinaryCodec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BinaryCodec.html) from commons apache [commons-codec](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4).

```
String headerb = "00110011000000011001000000000001001011000000000100000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
BinaryCodec codec = new BinaryCodec();
//I have no idea why this method is not static. 
//you may  use BinaryCodec.fromAscii(ascii.toCharArray()) instead
byte[] bval = codec.toByteArray(headerb);
File file = new File("test.epd");
Files.write(bval, file );

//Test that when the file is read, we retrieve the same string
byte[] byteArray = Files.toByteArray(file);
String asciiString = BinaryCodec.toAsciiString(byteArray);
System.out.println(asciiString);
```