# Android : convert binary string to byte

Tags: java, android, binary, byte

As the title says, I have to convert a binary string to byte format. My binary string contains only 6 bit data. I need to convert this 6 bit binary string to byte values

binary string

```
String s1 =  "111011";
String s2 =  "111000";
String s3 =  "000000";
String s4 =  "111000";
String s5 =  "110111";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert binary string to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727310/convert-binary-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: i hope i could help with my answer! if there are anymore questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it "manually" by converting it yourself

```
byte b = 0, pot = 1;
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    // -48: the character '0' is No. 48 in ASCII table,
    // so substracting 48 from it will result in the int value 0!
    b += (str.charAt(i)-48) * pot;
    pot <<= 1;    // equals pot *= 2 (to create the multiples of 2 (1,2,3,8,16,32)
}
```

This will multiply the bits with (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32) in order to determine the resulting decimal number.

Another possibility would be to really manually calculate the 6 binary digits into a decimal value:

```
byte b = (byte)
    ((str.charAt(5) - '0') * 1 +
    (str.charAt(4) - '0') * 2 + 
    (str.charAt(3) - '0') * 4 + 
    (str.charAt(2) - '0') * 8 + 
    (str.charAt(1) - '0') * 16 + 
    (str.charAt(0) - '0') * 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Byte.parseByte()` with a radix of 2 - [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(s1, 2);
```

Comment: I have tried this. but my binary string have only 6 bit data. I am getting an error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range for byte: "111011"

Comment: @Arya try using `StringUtils.leftPad(s1, 8, '0')`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an actual byte, or are you looking for a int?

```
String s = "101";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s,2));
```